# yii2:drop-down list for multiple values concat in one line

Tags: php, yii2

for my drop-down list I am using this code.

```
<?= $form->field($medicinerequest, '[' . $id . ']' . 'medicine_name')
->DropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Medicine::find()
->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'medicine_name','medicine_id' ),
[ 'prompt' => 'Please Select' ])?>
```

I am getting the drop-down list as in the picture. But I want it to be concatenated by hyphen(-) in one line. How can I do this?

[image: medicine-request-drop-down]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[`ArrayHelper::map($array, $from, $to, $group)`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#map%28%29-detail) uses [`ArrayHelper::getValue()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#getValue%28%29-detail) to obtain the values of `$from`, `$to` and `$group`. `ArrayHelper::getValue()` allows you to pass closures.

> The anonymous function signature should be: `function($array, $defaultValue)`.

As such you can set `$to` as

```
ArrayHelper::map(
    \app\models\Medicine::find()->asArray()->all(),
    'id',
    function($model) {
        return $model['medicine_name'].'-'.$model['medicine_id'];
    }
)
```

Comment: Though I will stick to my solution as this can be used at many places with one declaration. But you have explained well the proper way of doing it, I will accept your answer.

Comment: $model should be an array, not an object. So

return $model['medicine_name'].'-'.$model['medicine_id'];

Comment: @DiegoBetto thank you. For future reference you can edit the answer yourself to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution. I will welcome if there is a better solution.

I have created a function in the model Medicine.php

```
public function getMedicineName(){
        return $this->medicine_name .'-'.$this->medicine_id;
    }
```

and then in the arrayhelper replaced medicine_name with medicineName and Now I am getting what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous function could be

```
function ($element) {
   return $element['medicine_name'] . '-'. $element['medicine_id'];
}
```

You can check [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html)!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `$var` in kartik Depdrop widget, as the same scenario in the Dropdown widget here We use kartik depdrop widget

```
<?php

        $var = ArrayHelper::map(Modelname::find()->where(['id' => $model->customer_id])->all(), 'id',
            function ($model) {
                return $model['id'] .' - '. $model['name'];
            });
        echo $form->field($model, 'id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
            'data' => $var,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'depends' => [''],
                'url' => Url::to(['#'])
            ]
        ]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can populate it from a controller esp for dependant dropdown lists; you return key=>value pairs with values concatenated from model fields.

```
echo "<option value='".$model->id."'>"
.$model->field1.' '
.$modle->field2.' '.$model->field3."</option>";
```