# yii2 inserting 2 params as text inside dropdownlist

Tags: activerecord, drop-down-menu, yii2, html.dropdownlistfor

Here is yii2 drop down list.

```
 <?php  echo $form->field($model, 'param1')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(Model::find()->all(),'param1','param2');
```

It makes drop Down list with values of param1s and text to choose from of param2s.
So you see param2 texts , choose one and corresponding param1 value goes to server.

No my problem is that I want to do the same but show user not only param2 text but I want text to be constructed from param2+**param3**.

example of what I want.

hidden value___________text

1_____________________alpha

2_____________________bravo

3_____________________lima

hidden value___________text

1_____________________alpha-**red**

2_____________________bravo-**white**

3_____________________lima-**blue**

Is that possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [drop-down list for multiple values concat in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27769661/428543)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to do it will be using built-in ArrayHelper with [toArray()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#toArray%28%29-detail) method.

Put this in your model:

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

...

public static function getList()
{
    $initialModels = static::find()->all();
    $models = ArrayHelper::toArray($initialModels, [
        'app\models\YourModel' => [
            'param1',
            'combinedParam' => function ($model) {
                return "$model->param2 - $model->param3";
            },
        ],
    ]);

    return ArrayHelper::map($models, 'param1', 'combinedParam');
}
```

Displaying it in view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'param1')->dropDownList(YourModel::getList()) ?>
```

Comment: public static function getList() throws error "syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)"

Comment: Where you placed it? Check if syntax is correct - curly braces, etc.

Comment: right inside view

    <?php
    public static function getList()
    {
       ...
    }
    ?>

Just copy pasted your function

Comment: Check my answer accurately again, this should be placed in model, not view.