# Concatenation in Yii2 activeDropDownList

Tags: yii2, dropdown

Showing names of MilliStones in activeDropDownList of Yii2, but now i wants to concatenate another field with it(Like number of millistone).

e.g ( Milli Stone Name - Number of stones ).

```
<?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'milli_stone_id',ArrayHelper::map(MilliStones::find()->where(['cat_id' => $Rings->milli_cat])->all(), 'id', 'name'),['prompt'=>'Select Milli Stone','class'=>'form-control']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'milli_stone_id',ArrayHelper::map(MilliStones::find()->where(['IN', 'id', $IdsArray2])->asArray()->all(),
                    'id',
                    function($model, $defaultValue) {
                        return $model['id'].'-'.$model['name'];
                    }
                ),['prompt'=>'Select Milli Stone','class'=>'form-control']) ?>
```

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768540/yii2drop-down-list-for-multiple-values-concat-in-one-line

worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a select clause in find() this way

```
    <?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'milli_stone_id', 
        ArrayHelper::map(MilliStones::find()->
            select('id, concat(name, id) as name ')->
            where(['cat_id' => $Rings->milli_cat])->all(), 'id', 'name'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select Milli Stone','class'=>'form-control']) ?>
```